# Who to Hide Header And Side Bar component when login module loaded

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4 lazy loading. When I load login module I need to hide header and side bar components in app component.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="login">
   <app-sidebar></app-sidebar> 
   <app-top-bar></app-top-bar> 
</ng-template> 

<div class="cat__content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to components

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch : 'full'},
  {path : 'heroes', component : HeroDetailComponent, data : {some_data : 'some value'}}
];


class HeroDetailComponent {
      ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route
          .data
          .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

see http://plnkr.co/edit/tUe5fb?p=preview

Comment: but app component will load when app load..after that only modules..my code is in app component . so i don't think this way will not work for my solution

Comment: you can show the component when it matches the condition

Comment: just a variable login:boolean... i need to set this variable true, that what i need to know